# Inject function into tensorflow training loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a training loop that I would like inject a function, forexample:

```
def example():
    input("Press the <ENTER> key to continue...")
```

Here is my model

```
def main(unused_argv):
  assert FLAGS.input_file_pattern, "--input_file_pattern is required"
  assert FLAGS.train_dir, "--train_dir is required"

  model_config = configuration.ModelConfig()
  model_config.input_file_pattern = FLAGS.input_file_pattern
  model_config.inception_checkpoint_file = FLAGS.inception_checkpoint_file
  training_config = configuration.TrainingConfig()

  # Create training directory.
  train_dir = FLAGS.train_dir
  if not tf.gfile.IsDirectory(train_dir):
    tf.logging.info("Creating training directory: %s", train_dir)
    tf.gfile.MakeDirs(train_dir)

  # Build the TensorFlow graph.
  g = tf.Graph()
  with g.as_default():
    # Build the model.
    model = show_and_tell_model.ShowAndTellModel(
        model_config, mode="train", train_inception=FLAGS.train_inception)
    model.build()

    # Set up the learning rate.
    learning_rate_decay_fn = None
    if FLAGS.train_inception:
      learning_rate = tf.constant(training_config.train_inception_learning_rate)
    else:
      learning_rate = tf.constant(training_config.initial_learning_rate)
      if training_config.learning_rate_decay_factor > 0:
        num_batches_per_epoch = (training_config.num_examples_per_epoch /
                                 model_config.batch_size)
        decay_steps = int(num_batches_per_epoch *
                          training_config.num_epochs_per_decay)

        def _learning_rate_decay_fn(learning_rate, global_step):
          return tf.train.exponential_decay(
              learning_rate,
              global_step,
              decay_steps=decay_steps,
              decay_rate=training_config.learning_rate_decay_factor,
              staircase=True)

        learning_rate_decay_fn = _learning_rate_decay_fn

    # Set up the training ops.
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=model.total_loss,
        global_step=model.global_step,
        learning_rate=learning_rate,
        optimizer=training_config.optimizer,
        clip_gradients=training_config.clip_gradients,
        learning_rate_decay_fn=learning_rate_decay_fn)

    # Set up the Saver for saving and restoring model checkpoints.
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=training_config.max_checkpoints_to_keep)

  # Run training.
  tf.contrib.slim.learning.train(
      train_op,
      train_dir,
      log_every_n_steps=FLAGS.log_every_n_steps,
      graph=g,
      global_step=model.global_step,
      number_of_steps=FLAGS.number_of_steps,
      init_fn=model.init_fn,
      saver=saver)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

I tried adding in a function called tester:

```
def tester(x):
  print('test')
  return
```

And just before # Run training, I put

```
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
tf.py_func(tester, [inp], tf.float32)
```

Comment: That isn't a function, that's an expression.

Comment: Sorry, updated with what I'm going for.

Comment: You can use `tf.py_func` to run python code. Make sure you use `tf.control_dependencies` to block on it if you need.

Comment: @drpng great, I'm reading the docs, but it's a bit hard to understand how/where I would put this, could you show an example?

Comment: (I updated with what I did at the bottom of the question.)

Comment: It should read something like `f = tf.py_func(...)`, then you can use that as a node. For instance `with tf.control_dependencies([f]): a = b + c`, will trigger `f` everytime `a` is computed.